# Is there a music player that supports recursive playlists?

Tags: music-player, playlists

A recursive playlist is one in which each element of the list can be either a song or another playlist. It's a natural and powerful expansion of the concept of a playlist.  If there isn't a music player that supports recursive playlists, there should be.

Comment: Which players are under active development?